# How to concisely cascade through multiple regex statements in Python

Tags: python, regex, coding-style

My dilemma: I'm passing my function a string that I need to then perform numerous regex manipulations on.  The logic is if there's a match in the first regex, do one thing. If no match, check for a match with the second and do something else, if not check the third, and so forth.  I could do something like this:

```
if re.match('regex1', string):
    match = re.match('regex1', string)
    # Manipulate match.group(n) and return
elif re.match('regex2', string):
    match = re.match('regex2', string)
    # Do second manipulation
[etc.]
```

However, this feels unnecessarily verbose, and usually when that's the case it means there's a better way that I'm either overlooking or don't yet know about.

Does anyone have a suggestion for a better way to do this (better from a code-appearance standpoint, a memory usage standpoint, or both)?

Comment: Dupicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122277/how-do-you-translate-this-regular-expression-idiom-from-perl-into-python

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Similar question from back in september: [How do you translate this regular-expression idiom from Perl into Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122277)

Using global variables in a module maybe not the best way to do it, but converting it into a class:

```
import re

class Re(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.last_match = None
  def match(self,pattern,text):
    self.last_match = re.match(pattern,text)
    return self.last_match
  def search(self,pattern,text):
    self.last_match = re.search(pattern,text)
    return self.last_match

gre = Re()
if gre.match(r'foo',text):
  # do something with gre.last_match
elif gre.match(r'bar',text):
  # do something with gre.last_match
else:
  # do something else
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I didn't find that topic in my search, but it's spot on for what I'm trying to do. I like the idea of using a class rather than a module, too.

Answer (score 24):

Generally speaking, in these sorts of situations, you want to make the code "data driven". That is, put the important information in a container, and loop through it.

In your case, the important information is (string, function) pairs.

```
import re

def fun1():
    print('fun1')

def fun2():
    print('fun2')

def fun3():
    print('fun3')

regex_handlers = [
    (r'regex1', fun1),
    (r'regex2', fun2),
    (r'regex3', fun3)
    ]

def example(string):
    for regex, fun in regex_handlers:
        if re.match(regex, string):
            fun()  # call the function
            break

example('regex2')
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! This was what I was probably going to end up doing, but the overridden version of the re module is a slightly better fit for this project.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as yours. Here´s my solution:

```
import re

regexp = {
    'key1': re.compile(r'regexp1'),
    'key2': re.compile(r'regexp2'),
    'key3': re.compile(r'regexp3'),
    # ...
}

def test_all_regexp(string):
    for key, pattern in regexp.items():
        m = pattern.match(string)
        if m:
            # do what you want
            break
```

It´s a slightly modified solution from the answer of [Extracting info from large structured text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481862/extracting-info-from-large-structured-text-files)

Comment: Dictionaries don't guarantee ordering. You probably should use a sequence instead of a dict to get predictable behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... you could use something with the **`with`** construct... um

```
class rewrapper()
    def __init__(self, pattern, target):
        something

    def __enter__(self):
        something

    def __exit__(self):
        something


 with rewrapper("regex1", string) as match:
    etc

 with rewrapper("regex2", string) as match: 
    and so forth
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the manipulations for each regex similar?  If so, try this:

```
for regex in ('regex1', 'regex2', 'regex3', 'regex4'):
    match = re.match(regex, string)
    if match:
        # Manipulate match.group(n)
        return result
```

Comment: Unfortunately the manipulations vary for the different regex; in retrospect, I should have specified that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here your regexs and matches are not repeated twice:

```
match = re.match('regex1', string)
if match:
    # do stuff
    return

match = re.match('regex2', string)
if match:
    # do stuff
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class RegexStore(object):
   _searches = None

   def __init__(self, pat_list):
      # build RegEx searches
      self._searches = [(name,re.compile(pat, re.VERBOSE)) for
                        name,pat in pat_list]

   def match( self, text ):
      match_all = ((x,y.match(text)) for x,y in self._searches)
      try:
         return ifilter(op.itemgetter(1), match_all).next()
      except StopIteration, e:
         # instead of 'name', in first arg, return bad 'text' line
         return (text,None)
```

You can use this class like so:

```
rs = RegexStore( (('pat1', r'.*STRING1.*'),
                  ('pat2', r'.*STRING2.*')) )
name,match = rs.match( "MY SAMPLE STRING1" )

if name == 'pat1':
   print 'found pat1'
elif name == 'pat2':
   print 'found pat2'
```