# how can I combine a switch-case and regex in Python

Tags: python, switch-statement

I want to process a string by matching it with a sequence of regular expression. As I'm trying to avoid nested if-then, I'm thinking of switch-case. How can I write the following structure in Python? Thank you

```
switch str:
   case match(regex1):
       # do something
   case match(regex2):
       # do sth else
```

I know Perl allows one to do that. Does Python?

Comment: This is not legal syntax in Perl. Do you mean [given / when](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements) syntax?

Comment: @drewk: yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [pyswitch](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=display&name=pyswitch&version=1.2) (disclaimer: I am the author).  With it, you can do the following, which is pretty close to the example you gave in your question:

```
from pyswitch import Switch

mySwitch = Switch()

@myswitch.caseRegEx(regex1)
def doSomething(matchObj, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do Something
    return 1

@myswitch.caseRegEx(regex2)
def doSomethingElse(matchObj, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do Something Else
    return 2

rval = myswitch(stringYouWantToSwitchOn)
```

There's a much more comprehensive example given at the URL I linked.  pyswitch is not restricted to just switching on regular expressions.  Internally, pyswitch uses a dispatch system similar to the examples others have given above.  I just got tired of having to re-write the same code framework over and over every time I needed that kind of dispatch system, so I wrote pyswitch.

Answer (score 9):

First consider [why there is no case statement in Python](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-isn-t-there-a-switch-or-case-statement-in-python.htm). So reset you brain and forget them.

You can use an object class, function decorators or use function dictionaries to achieve the same or better results.

Here is a quick trivial example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

def hat(found):
    if found: print "found a hat"
    else: print "no hat"

def cat(found):
    if found: print "found a cat"
    else: print "no cat"

def dog(found):    
    if found: print "found a dog"
    else: print "no dog"

st="""
Here is the target string
with a hat and a cat
no d o g 
end
"""

patterns=['hat', 'cat', 'dog']
functions=[hat,cat,dog]

for pattern,case in zip(patterns,functions):
    print "pattern=",pattern
    case(re.search(pattern,st))
```

C style case / switch statements also "fall through, such as:

```
   switch(c) {
       case 'a':
       case 'b':
       case 'c':  do_abc();
                  break;
       ... other cases...
   }
```

Using tuples and lists of callables, you can get the similar behavior:

```
st="rat kitten snake puppy bug child"

def proc1(st): print "cuddle the %s" % st
def proc2(st): print "kill the %s" % st
def proc3(st): print "pick-up the %s" % st
def proc4(st): print "wear the %s" % st
def proc5(st): print "dispose of the %s" %st
def default(st): print "%s not found" % st

dproc={ ('puppy','kitten','child'): 
            [proc3, proc1], 
        ('hat','gloves'): 
            [proc3, proc4], 
        ('rat','snake','bug'): 
            [proc2, proc3, proc5]}

for patterns,cases in dproc.iteritems():
    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.search(pattern,st):
            for case in cases: case(pattern)
        else: default(pattern)    
        print
```

This gets the order for the found item correct: 1) pick up child, cuddle the child; 2) kill the rat, pick up the rat... It would be difficult to do the same with a C switch statement in an understandable syntax.

There are many other ways to imitate a C switch statement. Here is one (for integers) using function decorators:

```
case = {}

def switch_on(*values):
    def case_func(f):
        case.update((v, f) for v in values)
        return f
    return case_func

@switch_on(0, 3, 5)
def case_a(): print "case A"

@switch_on(1,2,4)
def case_b(): print "case B"

def default(): print "default"

for i in (0,2,3,5,22):
    print "Case: %i" % i
    try: 
        case[i]()
    except KeyError:
        default()
```

To paraphrase Larry Wall, Tom Christiansen, Jon Orwant in [Programming Perl](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=738558) regarding understanding context in Perl:

> You will be miserable programming Python until you use the idioms that are native to the language...

Answer (score 4):

A quick search shows a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597476/how-to-concisely-cascade-through-multiple-regex-statements-in-python) asked earlier with multiple work arounds.  May favorite solution from that one is by Mizard

```
import re

class Re(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.last_match = None
  def match(self,pattern,text):
    self.last_match = re.match(pattern,text)
    return self.last_match
  def search(self,pattern,text):
    self.last_match = re.search(pattern,text)
    return self.last_match

gre = Re()
if gre.match(r'foo',text):
  # do something with gre.last_match
elif gre.match(r'bar',text):
  # do something with gre.last_match
else:
  # do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're avoiding if-then, you can build on something like this:

```
import re

# The patterns
r1 = "spam"
r2 = "eggs"
r3 = "fish"

def doSomething1():
    return "Matched spam."

def doSomething2():
    return "Matched eggs."

def doSomething3():
    return "Matched fish."

def default():
    return "No match."

def match(r, s):
    mo = re.match(r, s)
    try:
        return mo.group()
    except AttributeError:
        return None

def delegate(s):
    try:
        action = {
            match(r1, s): doSomething1,
            match(r2, s): doSomething2,
            match(r3, s): doSomething3,
        }[s]()
        return action
    except KeyError:
        return default()
```

Results

```
>>> delegate("CantBeFound")
0: 'No match.'
>>> delegate("spam")
1: 'Matched spam.'
>>> delegate("eggs")
2: 'Matched eggs.'
>>> delegate("fish")
3: 'Matched fish.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question regarding Perl style switch statements is ambiguous. You reference Perl but you are using a C style switch statement in your example. (There is a deprecated module that provides C style switch statements in Perl, but this is not recommended...)

If you mean Perl [given / when type switch statements](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-statements), this would not be trivial to implement in Python. You would need to implement [smart matching](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Smart-matching-in-detail) and other non-trivial Perl idioms. You might as well just write whatever in Perl?

If you mean [C style switch statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Selection_statements), these are relatively trivial in comparison. Most recommend using a dictionary dispatch method, such as:

```
import re

def case_1():
    print "case 1"
    return 1

def case_2():
    print "case 2"
    return 2

def case_3():
    print "case 3"
    return 3

def default():
    print "None"
    return 0

dispatch=   {  
            'a':            case_1, 
            'g':            case_2, 
            'some_other':   case_3,
            'default':      default
            }

str="abcdefg"

r=[dispatch[x]() if re.search(x,str) else dispatch['default']() 
             for x in ['a','g','z'] ]

print "r=",r
```

Comment: I am going to use lambdas here to make the expression of the cases more declarative.  Thanks for the inspiration!